# Error imporing an audio file usinng require in expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to call this function and pass the audio name as a prop but I am getting this Error

```
error: src\components\Functions.js: src\components\Functions.js:Invalid call at line 72: require("../../assets/" + audioName)
```

```
  export const useAudioPlayer = (audioName) => {
    const [sound, setSound] = useState();
    
    async function playSound() {
            const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require(`../../assets/${audioName}`));
;
      setSound(sound);
    await sound.playAsync();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return [playSound];
}
```

***calling it in another component***

```
  const [ playSound ] = useAudioPlayer('pop.mp3');

    const HandlePress = () => {
    playSound()   
   }
```

the prop is being passed correctly, and it's a string, but for some reason, it shows that Error, anyway when I import the file directly as a hardcoded, it works well

```
 const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require(`../../assets/pop.mp3`));
```

**solutions I tried, but didn't work out**

```
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require("../../assets/" + audioName));
```

---

using babel-plugin-module-resolver

```
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require(`@assets/${audioName}`));
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the value inside of the `require` statement needs to be a static string - no variables allowed.

Comment: @Slbox is there another way to import the audio that I can pass props rather than ``` require``` ?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry. Your best best will probably be to use a script in advance to generate the require statements. I am not the end-all-be-all of knowledge on this point though so don't take that as a hard no.